# Node with Google Spreadsheet shows error when the node application runs

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api

When I run the node application it shows the following logs in a terminal,

```
(node:6929) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: HTTP error 400 (Bad Request) - <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, spreadsheets and presentations"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/common/drive_favicon1.ico"><title>Page not found</title><link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Product+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><style nonce="p9QWgciXJsUAuI7tmIRBAw">/* Copyright 2019 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. */
.goog-inline-block{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block}* html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}*:first-child+html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}#drive-logo{margin:18px 0;position:absolute;white-space:nowrap}.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url('//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png');background-size:116px 41px;display:inline-block;height:41px;vertical-align:bottom;width:116px}.docs-drivelogo-text{color:#000;display:inline-block;opacity:0.54;text-decoration:none;font-family:'Product Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:32px;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;position:relative;top:-6px;left:-7px;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min-resolution:144dpi){.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url('//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png')}}</style><style type="text/css" nonce="p9QWgciXJsUAuI7tmIRBAw">body {background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}a, a:link, a:visited {color: #112ABB;}</style><style type="text/css" nonce="p9QWgciXJsUAuI7tmIRBAw">.errorMessage {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%;}</style></head><body><div id="outerContainer"><div id="innerContainer"><div style="position: absolute; top: -80px;"><div style="margin: 18px 0; position: absolute; white-space: nowrap;"><a href="//support.google.com/docs/"><img height="35px" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/common/product/spreadsheets_lockup1.png" alt="Google logo"/></a></div></div><div align="center"><p class="errorMessage" style="padding-top: 50px">Sorry, unable to open the file at present.</p><p> Please check the address and try again.</p><div style="background: #F0F6FF; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 35px; padding: 10px 125px; width: 300px;"><p><strong>Get stuff done with Google Drive</strong></p><p>Apps in Google Drive make it easy to create, store and share online documents, spreadsheets, presentations and more.</p><p>Learn more at <a href="https://drive.google.com/start/apps">drive.google.com/start/apps</a>.</p></div></div></div></div></body><style nonce="p9QWgciXJsUAuI7tmIRBAw">#outerContainer {margin: auto; max-width: 750px;}#innerContainer {margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px; margin-top: 80px; position: relative;}</style></html>
(node:6929) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6929) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My application code is as follows,

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const {promisify} = require('util');

const creds = require('./client_secret.json');

async function accessSpreadsheet(){
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet ('1I-hvqJjO0Gkm0awS38Wz9JhilXV1JyWN');
    await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
    const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
    const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
    console.log(`Title: ${sheet.title}, Rows: ${sheet.rowCount}`);
}

accessSpreadsheet();
```

Comment: I think that your script works. From your error message, it is considered that the reason of your issue is the ID of `1I-hvqJjO0Gkm0awS38Wz9JhilXV1JyWN` which is used as the Spreadsheet ID. I think that this file might be not Google Spreadsheet from the value length of `1I-hvqJjO0Gkm0awS38Wz9JhilXV1JyWN`. So please confirm the Spreadsheet ID you want to use, again.

Comment: @Tanaike I think you are correct. The spreadsheet which I used is in .XLSX format. I created a new Google Sheet and used it's ID to communicate. Now the script works and able to get the information. Thank You.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.